# VBA Matching multiple instances of the same name to see if salary amount matches, and whether there are two or more that were paid same amount

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, matching

I am very new to VBA, having compiled my first two macros only two days ago for the purpose of bank statement reconciliation. My issue though is that I've realized the next step is too complex for me to code myself, and I can't seem to find adaptable code.

I need to take a name, find it in a master file of about 600 names, and see whether it finds a match. The problem them is, frequently there will be two or more individuals with the same name that were either paid different amounts, or were paid the same amount.

I am looking for some help on how to approach this, what functions I would need to use and whatnot. Alternatively, if someone were willing to write this macro for me, I would be happy to Venmo them $10 for the help (by sending your handle to a temp email), as well as of course put a tick next to their answer. I've laid out logical process as I envision it below.

[image]

As the data is proprietary, above is a quick example of the data I made. On the left, we have the cleaned bank statement data, with the names in one column and their corresponding salary amounts in the next column. On the right is the master file where we want to reconcile. First off, we are searching only first names as that's how they show on the bank statement, they're Afghan names so the most duplicates we'd get is ~7. Second, a quick note is that the search needs to take place by period, which is a number from 1 to 9 in a column where a number corresponds to a month/bank statement. Here is the logical process:

Take name, i.e. John, from column D in the left spreadsheet (AKA statement), and search through names in column G in the right spreadsheet (AKA master file).

For each name (in period 1): does name match? 
If no, keep cycling until a match is found. 
If no match is found, move on to next name in statement.

If yes, does the salary amount in column E of statement match with that name's corresponding salary amount in column AV of master file?
If no, keep cycling through all of the names in master file until either a salary amount match is found,  or move on to next name in statement.

If yes, it does match, continue to cycle through all names in the master file to check whether there are any other individuals with the same name, and if so, whether one or more of them were paid the same amount.

If an individual does not share their name with anyone else, and the salary amounts in both spreadsheets match, put an "a" in column X.
If an individual shares his/her name with one or more others but his/her salary is unique, put "a" in column X.

If 2 or more individuals with the same name were paid the same amount, put the COUNT of these individuals in column Y. (just marking the instance with a "b" in column Y would be okay too). Ideally, this count would be put next to every instance that 2+ individuals with same name paid the same amount was found.

It looks like the code might be pretty clunky and slow, but all I need is for it to work, doesn't need to be efficient, given that it's all terribly tedious to do manually.

Any help with this would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: This is too lengthy and has too many parts (and no code at all).  Take the first task and *make a start* - see if you can code it, then post back if you run into problems (with your code) and people will help.  FYI a good guideline to consider is that  people here are happy to help *for free* but less keen to take on work for minimum wage.....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513)

Comment: Thank you for your words of advice. I'm new here and not sure how things work. I am considering hiring a freelancer on i.e. UpWork to write the code, however I'd need to get approval from a higher-up in the company, whereas I'm just an intern trying to automate data entry (the one thing I'm doing right now that sucks). The 10$ would've been from my own money - if I were to get approval the company would offer the freelancer a reasonable price. I will give a go at the first steps of this. Again, thank you!

Comment: @kltk7 I admire your effort to seek a solution through compensation. Unfortunately this site is a little resistant to that approach.

Comment: Would either of you or someone else have a reasonable estimate for cost of completion of this project at a fixed cost rate?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and screenshots, it looks like you can solve this relatively easily with two COUNTIFS formulas (no VBA required). In the following example, I'm going to assume that your cleaned bank statement data is in a separate excel workbook named "Bank Statement.xlsx", and the period data in your master file is in column "A":

The first step is to compare the First Name (column G) and Amount Paid (column AV) in your master file to the data range in your bank statement file (column D and E respectively) and count the number of times both are a match (anything greater than 0 indicates a match). In your master file, type the following formula in cell "X2":

```
=COUNTIFS('[Bank Statement.xlsx]Output'!$D$83:$D$88,G2,'[Bank Statement.xlsx]Output'!$E$83:$E$88,AV2)>0
```

The second step is to find any duplicate records in your master file where the Period (column A), First Name (column G) and Amount Paid (column AV) are the same. In your master file, type the following formula in cell "Y2":

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$6340,A2,$G$2:$G$6340,G2,$AV$2:$AV$6340,AV2)>1
```

The third step is to check if both conditions are TRUE. Insert another column in your master file (column Z) and type the following formula in cell "Z2"):

```
=AND(X2,Y2)
```

The final step is, of course, to copy the formulas in cells X2, Y2, and Z2 all the way down to the bottom of your data (row 6340). You can now filter by column Z to show only records with a value of TRUE.

Please note the position of the dollar ($) signs in the above formulas. They are essential to maintain the proper range references when copying the formulas down to the bottom of your data.

Hopefully you can adapt this example to fit your actual excel workbook.

Cheers!